# Why VSCode Android Emulator not working properly?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile, android-emulator

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mx8Qy.jpg)

I tried to Run Flutter App in VSCode Android Emulator on Windows 10 as a beginner for first time. But Android Emulator was not working properly as shown in the image. I re-installed android studio and the emulator and changed the device and Android version. But nothing changed. How can I fix this issue?

I re-installed android studio and the emulator and changed the device and Android version.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNcHN.jpg)